# Snapping doesn't work when many enterprise layers load

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, snapping

I am using Arcmap 10.6, when I have only limited number of enterprise layers loaded, the snapping experience process is painful. My cursor turns to "Busy" shape (the blue circle) and can't snap to the feature. I have no idea why it happens. Any solution?

Notes:
Everything is hosted on a server through a Virtual Machine. The virtual machine includes all the mapping software for an enterprise level, along with SQL 2012.

**Mapping Software:  Version 10.6**

ArcGIS Server

Portal for ArcGIS

Two ArcGIS Web Adaptors

SQL Server 2012

**Operating System**

Windows Server 2012 R2

**Memory**

32 gigs

**Internet Bandwidth**

50/50 mbps up/down

**Tested:**

1. Rebuilt the entire map..
2. Checked the map's data source in ArcCatalog
3. Ran MXD Doctor
4. Restarted ArcGIS services in Services
5. Set the Default map as Default_old and generated another Default map
6. Full Compression (Includes Reconcile & Post w/ Rebuild Indexes) 
   Python ~ nightly routine w/ log (Successful)
7. Restricted memory limits in SQL
8. Checked the snapping tool bar
9. Checked the tables
10. Restarted the database

Comment: I'm guessing you are consuming the feature classes through a feature service. If you consume the database feature classes directly in ArcMap through a database connection instead of a feature service do you see the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had identical experience. It was necessary to compress SDE to a state of 0 (reconcile and post all versions to default), then removing all named versions and replicas. After that, compress SDE states using compress tool. Then rebuild indexes - and this is important - both through the geodatabase rebuild index tool AND through SQL using index commands.

After that, I rebuilt the versions and snapping was returned. Now we go through these steps frequently, as data changes will require a robust indexing.